Computers as money holders (that used artificial intelligence to manage money)
We have cryptocurrencies where money is virtual but holders are people. What, if, the holder was a computer (and, the money, could either be real, or, a cryptocurrency).
What if to manage money, instead, of people, we could, also, have computers (as money holders and dispensers):
Suppose a computer was instructed to dispense money according to assessment following Asimov's criteria
Furthermore,
The computer could be instructed to dispense money according to a scheme
For example, a computer could be instructed to dispense manage take and give money according to the following scheme:

What is this person good at? Can they develop existing or not yet existing skills?

The skill must be safe

The skill must not make global wellbeing worse

if the fund was private, one could add, one must not have harmful intentions towards a set, group, of people


Based on the assessment, money, could be dispensed (in, adequate, amounts)
It makes sense, that, if the computer had to manage the world, it could have an infinite supply of money
Note: I wanted to add the financial-constraints tag, but, could only, include five tags
The question is, how would things work if a computer could be a money holder, that worked to manage money according to criteria that improved overall wellbeing and did not make things worse. Is there anything in the real world, that, does this?

I feel more than a question of logistics, it is more so a question of ethics, which is inherent in any technology involving AI, more so when it involves such a sensitive topic like finances.
Isaac Asimov's Three Laws of Robotics are a set of instructions for robots to prevent them from malfunctioning dangerously:
First Law: A robot must not harm a human or allow a human to come to harm.
Second Law: A robot must obey human orders, unless those orders conflict with the First Law.
Third Law: A robot must protect itself, unless that protection conflicts with the First or Second Law.
So this risk of malfunction is magnified dangerously in matters of money.
If we talk of real life examples, maybe computer games esp online poker games could be an answer.
